# What revision library does stackoverflow use?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, revisions-list

I've read through [What was Stack Overflow built with?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with) and a few searches but can't find much information about how the team built the revision side to the software.

What libraries or resources were used, if any, to build the revisioning and allow it to recognise HTML and none-HTML changes? Or is that a trade secret?

Comment: I'm 90% sure that it is a home brewed solution.

Comment: How many deleted answers are there to this question?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LCS + love

Comment: @waffles: what does loving your Local Comic Shop have to do with anything?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [CodingHorror: Mixing Oil and Water: Authorship in a Wiki World](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001222.html)

> I played around with Levenshtein for a while, but even optimized implementations are brutally slow as the size of the input increases. I quickly realized that a line-based comparison was the only workable one. We used this [C# implementation](http://www.mathertel.de/Diff/DiffDoku.aspx) of An [O(ND) Difference Algorithm and its Variations (pdf)](http://xmailserver.org/diff2.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Did a little searching and I bet it is home grown.  But there are libraries out there that current do this type of revisions.

http://www.mathertel.de/Diff/Default.aspx