# How does SO store revisions?

Tags: discussion, revisions-list, database-design

How does SO store its revisions in the database?

Does it use diffs?
If so, what algo does it use?

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new.  If you compose a query, you'll see the schema that SE sites use.  It appears there's a PostHistory table.

Comment: @Mark, the datadumps are not necessarily a 100% copy of The Real Thing, I guess? But surely close enough to answer this question indeed – maybe post as an answer? Some additional detail: the PostHistory indeed [holds the Markkdown](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48596/when-does-the-question-answer-text-get-converted-from-markdown-to-html/48598#48598). Also related: [What revision library does stackoverflow use?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24313/what-revision-library-does-stackoverflow-use)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it does not store diffs. The complete source of each version is simply kept for each revision.

Although the exact implementation might differ we can peek at the [database schema for SEDE and the Data Dump](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/158100) that roughly matches the production database. In there we find the PostHistory table which hold the initial revision for a post with typeid's 1,2 and 3 (body, title, tags respectively) and any subsequent revisions for typeid's 4,5 and 6.

Looking at the rows for a single post, for example [Adding a list of objects to a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38229214) you'll find this:

[image]
<sup>*Click the image for the SEDE query*</sup>

In the text column you'll find the exact content as submitted, aka the markdown, much similar as when you go through the [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/38229214/revisions) and then click on the [source](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/dd12d122-a992-4bed-8854-13a8d5e14f78/view-source) for a specif revision.

If you want to know if both body, tags and titles were edited in a single revision, pay note to the revisionGuid column. Records with same Guid denote a single revision.

What you see on a page when you're offered a diff view of two revisions is generated on the fly by a proprietary  C# implementation as explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/34109/158100)