# GDPR Request: Post Edit does not contain the edit

Tags: feature-request, edits, questions, gdpr

`X\PostHistory.json` contains the *Initial Title*, *Initial Tag*, *Initial Body*, *Edit Title*, *Edit Tag*, and *Edit Body*. But it does not contain what exactly was edited!

Comment: Are those fields empty? What do you mean with: *it does not contains what exactly was edited*

Comment: If you expect the diff to be stored, that is a false assumption: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/297037/158100

Comment: Diffs aren't really information. They're an interpretation or derivation of two versions of information. It doesn't really make sense to store a diff for every revision, especially when there are about a million different diff generators in the world.

Comment: Are those actually literal (e.g., *"Initial Body"*)? (Not a rhetorical  question.)

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q yes, that is now posthistorytypeid's are named in its corresponding type table: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1431362

Answer (score 2):

Summarizing the comments into an answer:

> If you expect the diff to be stored, that is a false assumption: [meta.stackexchange.com/a/297037/158100](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/297037/158100)

As the linked answer says:

> No, it [the database] does not store diffs. The complete source of each version is simply kept for each revision.

and:

> What you see on a page when you're offered a diff view of two revisions is generated on the fly by a proprietary C# implementation as explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/34109/158100)

Another comment:

> Diffs aren't really information. They're an interpretation or derivation of two versions of information. It doesn't really make sense to store a diff for every revision, especially when there are about a million different diff generators in the world.

Providing "exactly was edited" for GDPR requests will not be implemented because it isn't stored and it doesn't make sense to store it in the first place. If you want to see a diff of the edit, use any one of those "million different diff generators" - plenty are online and free.